# Do I really need downcasting on Rust?

Tags: rust

Suppose I have 2 traits:

```
pub trait VpnProvider {
    fn connect();
}

pub trait RtspClient {
    fn connect();
    fn set_vpn_provider(Arc<Mutex<dyn VpnProvider>>);
}
```

Now suppose I want to hold them both on a `Stream`. I want to do that because I want my streams to have parts that can be switched live. So I can switch the `rtsp_client` if I want, the `vpn_provider`, etc. That's why I'm using 'pointers to implementation'.

```
struct Stream {
    pub rtsp_client: Arc<Mutex<dyn RtspClient>>,
    pub vpnProvider: Arc<Mutex<dyn VpnProvider>>
}
```

Ok, so, `rtsp_client` has its own `VpnProvider` pointer. The rtsp client should use this `VpnProvider` to send packets. But since there can be lots of VPN clients (OpenVPN, Wireguard, etc), they might not have a common interface. So for the rtsp client to interact with the connection, it should downcast to its specific VPN type and interact with it.

That's how I do it in C++: it uses downcasting to the appropriate type using `std::dynamic_pointer_cast<OpenVPN>` (for example) on `std::shared_ptr<VpnProvider>` and tests if the downcasting works, otherwise it tries another type.

I could not think about another design pattern. However I'm trying to avoid using these Rust libs that simulate downcasting. If there's no official support for downcasting on the language, then there might be a better way for solving this.

Comment: What's the point of having a `VpnProvider` trait if you can't use it without downcasting to the concrete type? Shouldn't all that client-specific detail be abstracted away by the trait? You say "they might not have a common interface" but a trait *is* a common interface. If the trait isn't expressive or general enough to let you do what you need to do with a `VpnProvider` then maybe you just need to add more functionality to it so that downcasting is not necessary.

Comment: If that's not a reasonable solution, anything you can do with downcasting, you could do with an `enum` instead without loss of generality (because downcasting requires you to know all the possible types at the use site, just like `enum`s do). So maybe turning `VpnProvider` into an `enum` would be an acceptable alternative?

Comment: @trentcl yes! That's what I was looking for, thanks :)